# Failed install of 14.04 which has resulted in error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_colour' not found

Tags: dual-boot

After an attempt to install 14.04 over 13.04 (which was working fine), I have the error msg at start up

error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found.
grub rescue>

I have tried to re-install again once, I cannot burn everything and start again. Only using  Ubuntu partition for testing etc...but cannot write over other Win7 partition it contains EVERYTHING and just before I was about to run backup :(

I have booted into the demo mode of 14.04 fine any reason I cannot repair from here using suggestions mentioned in other cases? Any suggestions....and many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Boot info - https://paste.ubuntu.com/7469770

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions in bug report, none seem to work for everyone.

Ubuntu 14.04 Update breaks grub, resulting in "error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found"

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977

One choice:
You need to chroot &   use 
dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc instead of grub-install directly, so that the system knows that it needs to run grub-install on that drive the next time grub is upgraded.
Or if UEFI:

```
dpkg-reconfigure grub-efi-amd64
```

Some find Boot-Repair works, others do not.

Comment: Boot repair will not work..tried but failed. Using a Legacy/UEFi boot option so non specific should boot?

Comment: Did you try the full chroot uninstall all versions of grub and reinstall? Not just the auto fix.